# RewriteEngine inside multiple htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 .htaccess files, onde inside /aaa and another inside /aaa/bbb.

When in both files I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

The rules of the first htaccess (/aaa) are completely ignored and only the rules of the second (/aaa/bbb) are interpreted. What is even stranger is that if I have many rules inside the first htaccess (/aaa) and NONE inside (/aaa/bbb) BUT I keep the linke above inside the htaccess of /aaa/bbb all the rules inside /aaa/.htaccess are still ignored.

How can I have multiple files with RewriteEngine On and have apache to respect all of them in order of the tree directory (low directory first and high last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have multiple files with RewriteEngine On and have apache to respect all of them in order of the tree directory (low directory first and high last).

In your `aaa/bbb/.htaccess` you should be using `RewriteOptions` as:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Note that it will have this behavior:

> Rules inherited from the parent scope are applied after rules specified in the child scope

**EDIT:**

If you use `InheritBefore` the order will be inverted (which is what OP needed at first place), i.e. **the parent rules will be executed first and the child ones later.**

[See official documentation for mode details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions)

Comment: So the rules from /aaa/bbb will be executed first and the rules from /aaa will the executed at last?

Comment: Great, I just did a test and it worked perfectly!! I still didnt approve your answer cause SO says I need to wait 6 minutes. One final question my friend: I have many customers inside /aaa directory like /aaa/ccc and like /aaa/ddd... How can I make the "RewriteOptions Inherit" default to all htaccess files? Is there any configuration in httpd.conf that I can make?

Comment: WOW I think I can use InheritDownBefore in the parent most htaccess file so all child will inherit without the need to specify inside all the htaccess child files riht?

Comment: Yes `InheritDownBefore` is very useful as you don't need to use `RewriteOptions` in all the child `.htaccess` files. It is only available after Apache `2.4.8` though

Comment: I tried using InheritDownBefore and I got 500 error! :( So I will have to update my apache. Do you know what is strange? I used "RewriteOptions InheritBefore" in the top most parent and the rules of the parent are still being processed before the child so I didnt need to use InheritDownBefore . Why? I thought I would have to set InheritBefore in all the children but no, I just had to use it in the parent. Any idea why it worked?